# Issue about FileTransfer() download in PhoneGap

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have been developing a Phonegap App for Android and IOS. I am trying to download a file(.pdf) from server using FileTransfer() download, and it's working normally. But when I use fileTransfer.onprogress then it seems to download more than the size of the file (my file is 20Mb and it downloads 40Mb more than 2x).

```
fileTransfer.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
    if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
        var percent = progressEvent.loaded/progressEvent.total;
        //percent allways equal 2, than more 2x size of real file 
        console.log(percent);
    } 
};
//Else FileTransfer() upload working well.
```

[image]

I don't known why? Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not the only one experiencing this:

http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/5/1/Using-the-Progress-event-in-PhoneGap-file-transfers#c1D7DAFD0-D62D-FBCB-6ADA9A452CDD6A2E